# List Folders in S3 Bucket untill a certain depth only

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to get listing of s3 distinct folders till depth 5

for example if i have below objects in s3 bucket

```
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb1/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file1
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb1/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file2
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb1/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file3
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb2/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file1
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb2/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file2
inbound/publisher/segment/db2/tb1/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file11
inbound/publisher/segment/db2/tb2/yyyy/mm/dd/hhmmss/file31
```

output should be like:

```
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb1
inbound/publisher/segment/db/tb2
inbound/publisher/segment/db2/tb1
inbound/publisher/segment/db2/tb2
```

i have made use of boto3 library in below code and tried getting the result by making use of paginator.

but paginator is yeilding entire list, can some help me to obtain the expected output as above.

here is my code.

```
import boto3

S3 = boto3.client('s3', 'eu-west-1')
PAGINATOR = S3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  bucket_name = "sample_bucket"
  prefix_key = "inbound/publisher/"

  pages = PAGINATOR.paginate(
      Bucket=bucket_name,
      Prefix=prefix_key
  )
  obj_list = []
  for page in pages:
    if 'Contents' in page:
      for obj in page['Contents']:
        obj_list.append({'Key': obj['Key']})
      print(obj_list)
    else:
      print('No Contents Found')
```

but above code returns entire list of objects, i tried using Delimiter='/' while passing argument to paginate, but then it goes to else block and prints no contents found.

Regards
Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the below code working for me :)

```
import boto3

S3 = boto3.client('s3', 'eu-west-1')
PAGINATOR = S3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = "sample_bucket"
    prefix_key = "inbound/publisher/"

    pages = PAGINATOR.paginate(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Prefix=prefix_key
    )

    obj_list = []

    # Extracting the List untill depth of our choice here till 5th level
    for page in pages:
        if 'Contents' in page:
            for obj in page['Contents']:
                obj['Key'] = '/'.join(obj['Key'].split('/')[0:-6])
                obj_list.append(obj['Key'])
        else:
            print('No Contents Found')

    ##Removing Duplicate values by converting object in list to dict and then again back to list##

    obj_list = list(dict.fromkeys(obj_list))
    print(obj_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mahi try this...

```
bucket_name='new-bucket-affe3d3c'   
prefix='inbound/publisher/segment/'
delimiter='/'

paginator= s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
for response_iterator in paginator.paginate(
   Bucket=bucket_name,
   Prefix=prefix,
   Delimiter=delimiter
):
#pprint(response_iterator)

#folders -> CommonPrefixes
if 'CommonPrefixes' in response_iterator:
    for obj in response_iterator['CommonPrefixes']:
        print(obj)

#files -> Contents
if 'Contents' in response_iterator:
    for obj in response_iterator['Contents']:
        print(obj)

output:
{'Prefix': 'inbound/publisher/segment/db/'}
{'Prefix': 'inbound/publisher/segment/db2/'}
```

Since db and db2 are different under segment...
Hope it helps...
r0ck

Comment: Hi Rock, Thanks for posting this piece of code and this works if we are giving input till segement level. I want the input to be till inbound/publisher/. If i give that as input its returning only one output: {'Prefix': 'inbound/publisher/segment/'}. But i want to gain output till tb level that is till 5 level depth.